# Como exibir uma imagem hospedada no meu App?

Tags: c#, winforms, imagem, picturebox

Gostaria de exibir uma imagem promocional dentro de um `PicutreBox` no meu app, porém essa imagem vai variar conforme a promoção que a Empresa for efetuar.

Existe algum código que esse `PictureBox` mostre uma determinada imagem que esteja hospedada em algum lugar?

Algo parecido com HTML, quando precisamos puxar uma imagem de um Host ou FTP, usamos:

```
src="img/logobranco.png"
```

Algum codigo em C# que faça a mesma função?

Comment: Windows Forms? WPF? Web Forms? ASP.NET MVC? Nancy? C# é "só" a linguagem de programação...

Comment: Estou usando Windows Forms.

Comment: Você quer usar uma imagem da web pra colocar no `PictureBox`?

Comment: @jbueno Buscada na Web ou Conseguida a partir de um banco de dados, ftp..

Comment: Cada caso é um caso diferente. Basicamente, tendo o endereço da imagem (desde que seja público) é só colocar o caminho na propriedade que eu falei abaixo. Ou então, desde que você tenha um objeto **`Image`** é só definir a propriedade `Image` do `PictureBox`. Se sua dúvida é justamente como "instanciar uma `Image`" a partir destes *sources*, é melhor abrir uma pergunta específica explicando isso. E mais, vai precisar de uma pergunta pra cada tipo (FTP, HTTP, Banco de dados, *file system* local, etc.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É só definir a propriedade **`ImageLocation`** do **`PictureBox`** com o endereço da imagem.

Ex.:

```
pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "https://www.site.com/images-winforms/promocao-principal.jpg";
```

Comment: Maravilha, funcionou !